# rsync over SSH with cron in osx-environment

Tags: macos, ssh, cron, rsync

I want to automatically download files and folders from a Linux server to which I have an SSH (and FTP) account. The files shall be downloaded on a **regular basis** (I suppose a cron is the right tool to do so) onto an OS X machine.

I tried the following rsync command, which works fine:

```
rsync -avzbe ssh account@server.tld:/www/htdocs/something/somefolder /Users/me/folder/foo/
```

However I have to enter the account's password every time (the SSH account on the server machine). The server is a managed one and I'm afraid I can't change the password.

Here are my questions:

- How do I bypass the entering of the password by storing it somewhere
- How do I automate this then correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `ssh-keygen` and accept the defaults in every step
2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@host.com "mkdir -p ~/.ssh/; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 700 ~/.ssh/; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`
3. Edit the crontab with `crontab -e` and add a line like `20 4,16 * * * rsync -a someuser@somehost.com:somedir/subdir ~/somedir`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options,

- set up a 
  [passwordless login](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh (for remote hosts where you don't have permission to change OS files)

Comment: The second one looks promising, I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend the first option; having passwords sitting around in plaintext is always a bad idea. There's somewhat less security exposure if someone steals an SSH private key.

Comment: Agreed. There are some real world weird touchy clients who don't allow other companies to edit even one file in their servers though..
I've suggested that as an alternative as I interpreted Martin has his hands tied considering any change in the remote host: 
"The server is a managed one and I'm afraid I can't change the password ...How do I bypass the entering of the password by storing it somewhere"