# How to setup a cronjob to auto download a file on Mac?

Tags: macos, cron

I'd like to setup a cron job to auto weekly download a file from my web hosting. I'm running OS X.6.8.

I want to specify the folder that the file downloads into.

How can this be done? I just want to overwrite the same file each time.

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: If the file isn't available publicly and you're ok with passphraseless authentification, see [rsync over SSH with cron in osx-environment](http://superuser.com/questions/349918/rsync-over-ssh-with-cron-in-osx-environment/350159#350159)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Terminal, type `crontab -e`, press `i` to insert text and enter the following:

```
30 3 * * 0 curl http://superuser.com/questions/360848/how-to-setup-a-cronjob-to-auto-download-a-file-on-mac > Downloads/filename.html
```

Then save and quit by pressing `Escape`, typing `:wq`, and pressing `Enter`.

This will run the `curl` command to download a URL to `Downloads/filename.html` every Sunday (weekday with index 0) at 3:30 AM.

Comment: `cron` is available by OS X, but you could look into `launchd` instead. It's Apple's general purpose program launcher, daemon and service manager, watchdog and task scheduler and configured using property lists (XML files).

Comment: Quick question - by doing crontab -e I'm essentially seeing all the cron jobs? I.e I wanted to edit one I had setup so just did the same and edited and saved, is that ok? Also can I add another line underneath to do the same thing but from another web space?

Comment: @Rob Yes, you're editing all your cron jobs, one per line.

Answer (score 0):

wget with cron should work

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /path/to/output/file -q -b http://example.com/somefile.ext
```

This would download the file every 5 minutes. I have been informed that OS X does not include wget by default so this may not be the best solution.

Comment: `wget` is not installed on OS X by default.

Comment: My bad it's be a while since I've used OS X.

Comment: You can install wget though. Just get homebrew from here http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/, and then type `brew install wget`.