# How do I use rsync to sync my repo on my mac to university server where I have ssh access?

Tags: macos, ssh, rsync, zsh

I need to use my university's ssh access and run my programs there for testing. I don't have sudo access there. It doesn't have vncserver there either. I would work with vim and make but I need git at least. Now I am looking into rsync to sync my current source directory into a remote directory and I'll ssh into the directory and run my make file to test it. I am looking at the man page of rsync and it looks very complicated. Can anyone please help me with this? I have googled in superuser and all commands seem different for different cases.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like `rsync -a --delete ~/Sites/site/ user@host.com:public_html` to upload my website.

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)
    --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
-r, --recursive             recurse into directories
-l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
-t, --times                 preserve times
-g, --group                 preserve group
-o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
-D                          same as --devices --specials
    --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
    --specials              preserve special files
```

See also [rsync over SSH with cron in osx-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/349918/rsync-over-ssh-with-cron-in-osx-environment/350159#350159).