# Is there an OSX application to sync a folder on your computer to a folder over FTP?

Tags: macos, sync, ftp

I've tried Expandrive / Macfuse as suggested on other questions, but it's TERRIBLY slow. In fact, when I'm editing files located on the server on local VIM, VIM itself becomes laggy for some reason! Instead I just want a solution that maps a folder on my local system to a folder on FTP. Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/149385/map-ftp-server-as-a-local-drive-in-finder

Comment: @GKoe I've stated I've already looked that kind of solution and it didn't work.

Comment: Consider osxfuse/sshfs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510421/sshfs-for-osx-10-8-mountain-lion

Comment: @GKoe I've tried, it's slow, I need something that uploads files that are changed locally, without trying to sync the opposite direction.

Comment: Dare I suggest Dropbox?

Comment: @GKoe That's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) by Panic. It can do all sorts of things over (S)FTP, map virtual drives, sync folders (in either direction), and anything else you'd want an FTP client to do. There's a trial period before you have to buy, but it's only US$34 and supports a good small company. The program is very configurable, and you can even do "trial runs" of transfers before really committing to a sync. It's also supposed to be faster than FUSE, and in my experience is more stable.

No, I don't work for them, and I'm not associated with them in any way, I just use Transmit a ton, and also use [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) for web coding stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I also use Transmit's sync feature with hosts that don't provide SSH access. You can also create a workflow for it:

[image]

If you have SSH access, you can use rsync ([and cron](https://superuser.com/questions/349918/rsync-over-ssh-with-cron-in-osx-environment/350159#350159)):

```
rsync -a --delete --exclude=.DS_Store ~/Sites/site/ user@host.com:public_html
```